# how to check for where in Linq C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

below is my code and i want do not want Storyid whose value is 0 to be included in  taskbugsworkitem.
 but story id value i am checking while selecting.i am still learning linq need help

```
  var taskbugsworkitem =
             (from w in workItemcollectionList where (w.Type.Name == "Task") || w.Type.Name == "Bug"  select new {
                 Id = w.Id,
                 Name = w.Title,
                 Type = w.Type.Name,
                 Storyid = (w.WorkItemLinks.Count > 0) ? w.WorkItemLinks[0].TargetId : 0,
                 status = w.State,
                 IterationPath = w.IterationPath,
                 Assignedto = w.Fields["Assigned To"].Value.ToString(),
                 priorty = Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["Priority"].Value),
                 effort = Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["effort"].Value),
                 Completed = (w.Type.Name== "Task") ? Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["Completed"].Value):0
             }) .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get `taskbugworkitem` which only has WorkItemLinks, then you can query like this :

```
var taskbugsworkitem =
             (from w in workItemcollectionList
              where (w.Type.Name == "Task" || w.Type.Name == "Bug") 
              && w.WorkItemLinks?.Count > 0
              select new
              {
                  Id = w.Id,
                  Name = w.Title,
                  Type = w.Type.Name,
                  Storyid = w.WorkItemLinks[0].TargetId ,
                  status = w.State,
                  IterationPath = w.IterationPath,
                  Assignedto = w.Fields["Assigned To"].Value.ToString(),
                  priorty = Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["Priority"].Value),
                  effort = Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["effort"].Value),
                  Completed = (w.Type.Name == "Task") ? Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["Completed"].Value) : 0
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: && w.WorkItemLinks?.Count > 0 is taking 6 min to process 8,000 records

Comment: Try using `&& w.WorkItemLinks?.Any()` instead of && `w.WorkItemLinks?.Count > 0`

Comment: any not coming @Akash

Comment: You mean, `Any` is giving result in same duration or not giving result at all?

Comment: ANY not coming !!

Comment: Your response still confusing me

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var taskbugsworkitem =
             (from w in workItemcollectionList where (w.Type.Name == "Task") || w.Type.Name == "Bug" && w.Storyid!=0 select new {
                 Id = w.Id,
                 Name = w.Title,
                 Type = w.Type.Name,
                 Storyid =w.Storyid,
                 status = w.State,
                 IterationPath = w.IterationPath,
                 Assignedto = w.Fields["Assigned To"].Value.ToString(),
                 priorty = Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["Priority"].Value),
                 effort = Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["effort"].Value),
                 Completed = (w.Type.Name== "Task") ? Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["Completed"].Value):0
             }) .ToList();
```

Comment: Storyid is not coming in w (basically Storyid not appearing after w dot)

Answer (score 0):

If I read you correctly `StoryId == 0` is solely the result of `w.WorkItemLinks.Count ==0`, so you want to filter such records out in `Where()` using `w.WorkItemLinks.Any()`  .

```
var taskbugsworkitem = workItemcollectionList
    .Where((w=>w.Type.Name == "Task" || w.Type.Name == "Bug")&& w.WorkItemLinks.Any())
    .Select(w=> new{
        Id = w.Id,
        Name = w.Title,
        Type = w.Type.Name,
        Storyid = w.WorkItemLinks[0].TargetId,
        status = w.State,
        IterationPath = w.IterationPath,
        Assignedto = w.Fields["Assigned To"].Value.ToString(),
        priorty = Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["Priority"].Value),
        effort = Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["effort"].Value),
        Completed = (w.Type.Name == "Task") ? Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["Completed"].Value) : 0 })
   .ToList();
```